# Why does antifreeze glow green?

Tags: chemicals

Why does antifreeze have that fluorescent green glow - as if it were some alien chemical in a science fiction film?

Is the glow caused by something added to antifreeze or is it inherent? All antifreezes seem to glow although the shades are different.

Comment: I think it used to come that way so the coolant would be recognized as such. You'll find today antifreeze comes in about a dozen different colors. Green is just one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Disodium fluorescein dyes are added to antifreeze to help trace the source of leaks, and as an identifier since some different colored formulations are incompatible"

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antifreeze)